# df data does not match fdisk data in LUKS encrypted partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems, encryption

I'm having issues trying to understand a LUKS encrypted setup at work in Ubuntu. It was done by someone before me with Ansible and roughly the process is as follows:

create a sparse file with DD
`dd of=/root/encfs bs=1 count=0 seek=40G`

format LUKS partition
`cryptsetup -y luksFormat /root/encfs`

open encrypt file
`cryptdisks_start datafs`

create filesystem
`mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/mapper/datafs`

mount partition:
`mount /dev/mapper/datafs /data`

The sparse file seems to be in a disk 30G but I think that somehow is actually on another disk which is 64G. I'm trying to change the size of that encrypted volume and I successfully made bigger the sparse file but df still shows it is 40G

Does anyone know how can I:
 - first, make sure the partition is on the disk I think it is
 - secondly, make use of the whole disk so the partition is 64G?
 - bonus question: is the sparse file really necessary?

I've tried deleting /root/encfs and recreating it, reformating the image path but none worked.

Any pointers/help would be highly appreciated as I couldn't find any help online.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seing is the `sparse` property of a sparse file: Only those parts of the file, that have been written at least once, will actually be allocated on disk.

The part, that is not (yet) allocated on disk is not yet actually used, so it doesn't show up on `du` or `df`

As an example: This is what I just did on my Ubuntu PC:

```
~$ df -h .
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/payload-home  2.8T  540G  2.1T  21% /home

~$ dd if=/dev/zero of=./test.sparse bs=1 count=0 seek=5000G
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes copied, 0.00022495 s, 0.0 kB/s

~$ ls -lh test.sparse 
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 4.9T Apr 29 17:23 test.sparse

~$ du -h test.sparse 
0   test.sparse

~$ df -h .
Filesystem                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/payload-home  2.8T  540G  2.1T  21% /home
```

So: While the disk has 2.1T free, I can easily create a 5T sparse file, which will show up as using zero bytes and no changes to `df`

If I were to populate that file, I would receive a "no space left on device" message after writing a touching over 2TB of blocks.

To answer your direct questions: `df -h /path/to/file` will tell you which partition or volume the file is on and how much space there is on that partition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me understanding the sparse bit, however, I still don't understand why the Luks encrypted partition does not change size to reflect the change in the sparse file it is based on. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: If you resize a volume (e.g. an encrypted LV), this doesn't automatically resize the file system on it. Depending on which you use, you need to employ something like `resize2fs`, `growfs`or friends.